# Firefox Private Browsing: how to set search bar to use google.com/ncr by default?

Tags: linux, firefox, google-search, private-browsing

Is there a place to change the Firefox installation so it uses google.com/ncr by default instead of the local google.com ?  Other than having to set cookies each time the browser is opened, or install third party extensions?

Previously posted solutions appear to be obsolete. In particular, searchplugins/google.xml and open-search-providers/google.xml do not exist.